# Create an enumerated list with dotfill after every item

Tags: table-of-contents, enumerate, enumitem, renewcommand

I'm trying to achieve a enumerated list with a `\dotfill` **after** every item to create a 'fake ToC'. But what I'm currently ending up is the dots **before** the item, not afterwards.

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{faketoc}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[faketoc]{label*=\textbf{.\arabic*}} \setlist[faketoc,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}}

\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\olditem\dotfill}

\begin{faketoc}
    \item One
    \begin{faketoc}
        \item Two
        \item Three
        \begin{faketoc}
            \item Two
            \item Three
            \item Four
        \end{faketoc}
        \item Four
    \end{faketoc}
    \item Five
    \item Six
\end{faketoc}
```

Which leads to the following output

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is

```
1 One ............................
  1.1 Two ........................
```

Would be glad if someone could help me out.

Comment: Are you open to doing this a different way, or does it have to be with "enumerate" for some reason? Do you want there to be *nothing* on the right side of the dots? That seems odd.

Comment: @frabjous I'd be open to a different way, enumerate felt just like a quite short and simple way. It is for a proposed 'table of contents' for a thesis so I want to achieve a toc-like look.

Comment: @woerndl if it's for a proposed thesis ToC, why not just use `\tableofcontents`? `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\tableofcontents\section{One}\subsection{Two}\end{document}` produces what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Or in fact (as much as I like using LaTeX) you could also just create a list of section headings with a text editor and give that to your advisor. No real need to use LaTeX for this.

Comment: @Skillmon I'm writing a whole Exposé/Proposal, the ToC is just one part. I tried making a second ToC using titletoc, minitoc and etoc but it was just a huge PITA (at least for me). I think I'm 80% there… I "just" wanted to add the \dotfill in a convienent way and thought it would be easy. If not I'll just add \dotfill to every item manually. And I wanted to understand how I could achieve it correctly.

Comment: If you don't mind writing `\item{One}` instead of `\item One`, then redefine `\item` by `\renewcommand\item[1]{\olditem #1\dotfill}`.

Comment: @gernot thank you so much, that's good enough! At least better than \dotfill in every single line :-)

Comment: @gernot I propose you copy/paste your comment as an answer to get this question out of the unanswered queue.

Comment: @scottkosty Done

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind writing `\item{One}` instead of `\item One`, then redefine `\item` by

```
\renewcommand\item[1]{\olditem #1\dotfill}
```

As @Lupino pointed out, this would interfere with all enumerated lists, so this change should only be activated for the `fakedoc` environment.

```
\let\faketocolditem\item
\newcommand\faketocitem[1]{\faketocolditem#1\dotfill}%
\AddToHook{env/faketoc/begin}{\let\item\faketocitem}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{faketoc}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[faketoc]{label*=\textbf{.\arabic*}} \setlist[faketoc,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}}
\let\faketocolditem\item
\newcommand\faketocitem[1]{\faketocolditem#1\dotfill}%
\AddToHook{env/faketoc/begin}{\let\item\faketocitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{faketoc}
\item{One}
  \begin{faketoc}
  \item{Two}
  \item{Three}
    \begin{faketoc}
    \item{Two}
    \item{Three}
    \item{Four}
    \end{faketoc}
  \item{Four}
  \end{faketoc}
\item{Five}
\item{Six}
\end{faketoc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With this solution, OP would be unable to have a list (numbered, unnumbered, or description) without those dots (unless, of course, they use `\olditem` instead of `\item`)... I'd suggest to overload the `\item` command within the scope of the `faketoc` environment.

Comment: @Lupino Thanks for the observation, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can tap into `\item` and `\end{faketoc}` to insert `\dotfill` before moving on to the next item. The following does that (not extensively tested).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{faketocaux}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[faketocaux]{label*=\textbf{.\arabic*}}
\setlist[faketocaux,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}}

\newcounter{faketocdepth}
\newif\iffirstitem
\newif\iflastitem
\NewDocumentCommand{\fakeitem}{}{%
  \iffirstitem
    \firstitemfalse
  \else
    \iflastitem
      \global\lastitemfalse
    \else
      \unskip\dotfill\mbox{}\par
    \fi
  \fi
  \olditem
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{faketoc}{O{}}{%
  \stepcounter{faketocdepth}% Step faketoc depth
  \ifnum\value{faketocdepth}=1
    \let\olditem\item
  \else
    \unskip\dotfill\mbox{}\par% Insert \dotfill for every item that's not the first
  \fi
  \begin{faketocaux}[#1]
    \firstitemtrue
    \let\item\fakeitem
}{%
    \unskip\dotfill\mbox{}\par% Insert \dotfill at \end{faketoc}
    \global\lastitemtrue
  \end{faketocaux}
  \addtocounter{faketocdepth}{-1}% Unstep faketoc depth
}

\begin{document}

\begin{faketoc}
    \item One
    \begin{faketoc}
        \item Two
        \item Three
        \begin{faketoc}
            \item Two
            \item Three
            \item Four
        \end{faketoc}
        \item Four
    \end{faketoc}
    \item Five
    \item Six
\end{faketoc}

\end{document}
```